# simple redirection for mobile device using php

Tags: php, html, mobile, browser-detection

I need a simple redirection for mobile user for website 
when user checks website using mobile automatically it should redirect to another webpage

will this work ????

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 800) {
 window.location = "http://m.domain.com";
}
//-->
</script>
```

i need a simple script to redirect mobile user
BECAUSE some say we need to use .htaccess file

- and i don't have any basic knowledge about .htaccess

Comment: yes this is the best approach, using JQuery you could detect screen resolution and then redirect to your mobile webpage

Comment: i don't need to detect resolution ,i need to detect device and redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.site.com/');
}
?>
```

OR this PHP class: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Comment: but your using script tag there

Comment: the script tag is not necessary, you can use header(). I have edited the code.